# Replacing every letter in a string using a loop

Tags: c, string, loops, replace

I have a string called "line" that contains a word. The word is random each time and I would like a loop that can replace each letter in the random word with an asterisk. So far I have a loop that can replace the letter e with an asterisk. Is there a way to modify this loop so that all letters are replaced, rather than just copying and pasting this loop 25 times with the remaining 25 letters? And for upper case letters too?

Thanks a lot.

```
  for (w = 0; w <= strlen(line); w++)
    {
        if (line[w] == 'e')
        {
            line[w] = '*';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `isalpha`? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha

Comment: Show the definition of `line`.

Comment: Just skip the check for `line[w] == 'e'`? It's not clear what your line looks like. Or check `isalpha(line[w])` if you just want letters and not other characters changed. And change `w <= strlen(line)` to `w < strlen(line)`.

Comment: `for (w = 0; w < strlen(line); w++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program will replace `"word"` with `"****"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char text[] = "This a paragraph of words where a random word should be replaced with * instead of word when word is found multiple times.";
    char find[] = "word ";

    printf("Start:  %s\n", text);

    while(strstr(text, find))
    {
        memset(strstr(text,find), '*', strlen(find)-1);
    }

    printf("Result: %s\n", text);

    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
Start:  This a paragraph of words where a random word should be replaced with * instead of word when word is found multiple times.
Result: This a paragraph of words where a random **** should be replaced with * instead of **** when **** is found multiple times.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop over the string character by character:

```
void to_asterisks ( char *line ) {
    while ( *line != '\0' ) {
        *line++ = '*';
    }
}
```

This works because all basic strings are NUL terminated, the `line` pointer is incremented until a NUL (a zero, shown above as char '\0') is reached. The function replaces characters in-place.

Answer (score -1):

Um, if you want to change all the letter to asterisks, why even do the condition?  Is this not what you want?

```
auto c = strlen(line);

for (w = 0; w < c; w++)
{
        line[w] = '*';
}
```